# Посоветуйте сборщик GUI для программ на С++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gui

Добрый вечер,разрабатываю GUI для своей проги остановился на QT4, но хотел так же узнать существует ли плагин для сборки GUI на eclipse С++ наподобие widowsBuilder который есть в eclipse java ?

Comment: Зачем Qt4, когда уже есть Qt 5.9 и вот-вот выйдет Qt6? А для создания GUI-приложений я бы посоветовал QML, входящий в состав Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> хотел так же узнать существует ли плагин для сборки GUI

Не понял вопрос. Вы спрашиваете - есть ли инструмент для быстрого создания интерфейса на Qt? Да, он существует -  QtCreator: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator